# Ubuntu: no boot - Error message: “mtd device must be supplied ”

Tags: boot

System (dual boot, Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10) does not boot: once selected Ubuntu at dual boot, I receive error message “mtd device must be supplied” - It shows on two lines, then boot does not go on.
I tried to boot through recovery mode, but the problem persists. Actually, the recovery mode seems to freeze as well.
I had to apply a forced shut down in order to attempt to reboot the laptop.
The problem has appeared last night (the system is constantly updated and upgraded).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was caused by a full hard drive.

You need to:

1. Boot to recovery mode (here is how: https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/270345 )
2. In Recovery Menu, enter root shell prompt
3. While in shell:

- Enter `df -h` to check if your disk is indeed 100% full
- If yes, delete some large files

This command might be helpful to find largest directories in your /home directory (might take a while to process):

```
$ sudo du -a /home | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I _had_ enough room until I caused a core dump... my system started having issues so I rebooted it, only to find that the core dump made my hard drive full and caused all the issues! Finding and removing the core dump file fixed it for me.