# help! system crashed on 22.04 update

Tags: 20.04, updates, 22.04

I updated from 20.04 to 22.04 and at first boot, I get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Ncx.jpg

How do I rescue my system?

error:

```
mtd device must be supplied. (device name empty)
```

or error:

```
.../netplan failed with exit status 127
```

If I try to boot to an older kernel.

I looked at

[mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty)

and the only solution provided is to ignore the error. In my case, I cannot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty)

Comment: @Organic Marble They say to ignore the error. I wish I could.