# mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

On Friday 12th August, When trying to upgrade UbuntuStudio 20.04.4 to 22.04.1 by the network:

- download was done correctly
- Upgrading progession was correct.[progression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGhm.jpg)

After restarting:

- the message "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)" was displayed[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH9xS.jpg)
- the login window doesn't appear, it stucks on the Ubuntustudio first display.[ubuntustudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb7Yd.jpg)

Most of answer on the forum does not match to solve the issue.

What does mean this message "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)"?

Does Anyone have a solution to fix it?

Regards

Raerband

Comment: Duplicate of [mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty)

Comment: Remove the mtd references from title and question or it will be closed as a duplicate of a warning message. You have another problem, not getting beyond the startup screen at first boot.  How long did you wait on this screen?

Comment: @ubfan1 waiting was up to one night

Comment: Likely a video problem.  What video hardware do you have(Nvidia,...?)? How did you install any proprietary drivers?  Many solutions here for such problems, start by cleaning out all packages installed for the video driver, remove any repositories added for video, and reinstall using the standard repos with ubuntu-drivers or the Software and Updates/Additional drivers. I and many others get the "mtd" message, it really is not a problem.

Comment: I had 100Gig of hard drive, 54% were used and 46% free; That's why i think, it is not a problem of storage space.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and have done for over a month now. No fixes have been made that eliminate my issue. I run a dual monitor system and the only way to boot for me is either:

1. Unplug *one* monitor while booting, and plug it back in once I have logged in, or
2. Boot via recovery mode, run a dpkg check (which returns zero issues), and then resume normal boot.

GPU: RTX 3080ti
GPU Driver: NVIDIA version 515.65.01
OS: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic 64-bit

There is a fix given [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622), however this does not solve my issue. If you scroll down, people have given other workarounds too, including making an edit to `etc/fstab`, although I do not know what I should be changing in there and therefore do not want to accidentally make matters worse for myself.

Comment: In my case, removing a couple of manual entries in /etc/fstab did solve the booting-to-recovery problem.