# Ubuntu 22.04 : can't connect to internet anymore (WiFi or ethernet)

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I switched to 22.04 last week (I was previously on 20.04, my first Ubuntu) and it worked fine until yesterday. I started having Wifi issues where I needed to turn it off and on again for it to work again. But on the third time in less than two hours, the WiFi icon on the top of my screen switched to the Ethernet icon. And from that point, I couldn't (and still can't) connect to internet. I've tried different WiFi connexions, Ethernet... It just doesn't work.
I've searched for solutions and found that there are quite a lot of WiFi issues with 22.04. I've tried what is suggested here : https://www.technewstoday.com/ubuntu-wifi-not-working/  but it's not working since I can't update anything without internet connexion...

Edit:
I have tried to change the kernel version without success. It doesn't seem to change anything for my problem.
Additional information:

- my kernel version is 5.15.0-46-generic. I've switched to 5.15.0-43-generic (the only choice) during boot, but it didn't change anything.
- I have the '[mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty)' message during boot.
- from the moment the problem appeared, the Ethernet connection icon is always displayed, no matter what.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks !

Edit 2 :
Here's the log :

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Electronics & Telecommunications RSH RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1058:1e25]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15d8] (rev c2)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo dmesg | grep rtw
```

[    2.513304] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 9.9.4, H2C version 15
[    2.513486] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 9.9.11, H2C version 15
[    3.001199] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.036755] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: start vif 5c:3a:45:06:32:31 on port 0
[  826.961117] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: sta 22:66:cf:40:c8:30 joined with macid 0

Comment: You gave no information that could help to resolve the issue. It is not related to "many Wi-Fi problems in 22.04". I can guess that a kernel update was interrupted. Try to boot with a previous kernel and update the system again.

Comment: I gave all the information that I have. Being a newbie, I don't know what information would be needed in such cases. But thanks! I will try that.

Comment: I tried to change kernel version but it didn't help unfortunately...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: It's updated :)

Comment: It looks good. BTW you don't need to type "Edit1, Edit2" all edits are tracked and can be seen by everyone, https://askubuntu.com/posts/1424966/revisions

Comment: Ok thanks ! Is there another thing I can check or just should I just revert to 20.04 ?

Comment: If it was working before and then suddenly stopped for no good reason, there is no reason to believe it will magically start working again in 20.04, unless you figure out what actually changed to make it stop.

Comment: The device should be working. You can see more information by `dmesg | grep rtw`

Comment: You can also install another driver from "Additional Drivers".

Comment: Added the logs. Where should I find those additional drivers? (Sorry for the lack of markup in my question, I'm doing this on my phone since I can't use my laptop...)

Comment: press the windows key(or command on a Mac keyboard) and begin typing "Additional Drivers" and press enter.

Comment: Alright thanks ! But I can't do anything on this screen... Remember that I can't access internet with my laptop...

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find any softer solution, I reinstalled Ubuntu (22.04) from scratch. It seems to be working for now. I will update if internet connexion is lost again.